# Python dictionary "plus-equal" behavior

Tags: python, dictionary, operators, magic-methods, mutators

I'm trying to understand the exact mechanism behind updating a python dictionary using `d[key] += diff`.  I have some helper classes to trace magic method invocations:

```
class sdict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, *args, **kargs):
        print "sdict.__setitem__"
        return super(sdict, self).__setitem__(*args, **kargs)
    def __delitem__(self, *args, **kargs):
        print "sdict.__delitem__"
        return super(sdict, self).__delitem__(*args, **kargs)
    def __getitem__(self, *args, **kargs):
        print "sdict.__getitem__"
        return super(sdict, self).__getitem__(*args, **kargs)
    def __iadd__(self, *args, **kargs):
        print "sdict.__iadd__"
        return super(sdict, self).__iadd__(*args, **kargs)
    def __add__(self, *args, **kargs):
        print "sdict.__add__"
        return super(sdict, self).__add__(*args, **kargs)

class mutable(object):
    def __init__(self, val=0):
        self.value = val
    def __iadd__(self, val):
        print "mutable.__iadd__"
        self.value = self.value + val
        return self
    def __add__(self, val):
        print "mutable.__add__"
        return mutable(self.value + val)
```

With these tools, let's go diving:

```
>>> d = sdict()
>>> d["a"] = 0
sdict.__setitem__
>>> d["a"] += 1
sdict.__getitem__
sdict.__setitem__
>>> d["a"]
sdict.__getitem__
1
```

We don't see any `__iadd__` operation invoked here, which makes sense because the left-hand side expression `d["a"]` returns an integer that does not implement the `__iadd__` method.  We do see python magically converting the `+=` operator into `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` calls.

Continuing:

```
>>> d["m"] = mutable()
sdict.__setitem__
>>> d["m"] += 1
sdict.__getitem__
mutable.__iadd__
sdict.__setitem__
>>> d["m"]
sdict.__getitem__
<__main__.mutable object at 0x106c4b710>
```

Here the `+=` operator successfully invokes an `__iadd__` method. It looks like the `+=` operator is actually being used twice:

- Once for the magic translation to `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` calls
- A second time for the `__iadd__` call.

Where I need help is the following:

- What is the exact, technical mechanism for translating the `+=` operator into `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` calls?
- In the second example, why is the `+=` operator used twice?  Doesn't python translate the statement to `d["m"] = d["m"] + 1`  (In which case wouldn't we see `__add__` be invoked instead of `__iadd__`?)

Comment: I'm guessing that since the "get the value of" operator has been implemented, the statement is considered equivalent to this: "X = get; X += 1; set(X);"

Comment: This all looks pretty straightforward to me.  `sdict.__iadd__` is never being invoked because you don't have any code that performs `+=` on an `sdict` object.  You're only performing `+=` on elements in the `sdict` -- in the first case an integer and in the second case a `mutable`.  But you already demonstrated that you understand this, so I'm not sure what the question is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the first example, you didn't apply the `+=` operator to the dictionary. You applied it to the value stored in the `d['a']` key, and that's a different object altogether.

In other words, Python will retrieve `d['m']` (a `__getitem__` call), apply the `+=` operator to that, then set the result of that expression back to `d['m']` (the `__setitem__` call).

The `__iadd__` method either returns `self` mutated in-place, or a new object, but Python cannot know for sure what the method returned. So it *has* to call `d.__setitem__('m', <return_value_from_d['m'].__iadd__(1)>)`, always.

The exact same thing happens if you did:

```
m = d['m']
m += 1
d['m'] = m
```

but without the extra name `m` in the global namespace.

If the `mutable()` instance was not stored in a dictionary but in the global namespace instead, the exact same sequence of events takes place, but directly on the `globals()` dictionary, and you wouldn't get to see the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` calls.

This is documented under the [augmented assignment reference documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements):

> An augmented assignment evaluates the target (which, unlike normal assignment statements, cannot be an unpacking) and the expression list, performs the binary operation specific to the type of assignment on the two operands, and assigns the result to the original target.

where `d['m']` is the target; evaluating the target here involves `__getitem__`, assigning the result back to the original target invokes `__setitem__`.

Comment: I think my confusion is in the actual mechanism in which python translates `+=` into `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` calls on the dictionary.  In the second example, it seems like it's using the one `+=` operator twice: once to invoke both `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`, and a second time to invoke `__iadd__` on `mutable`.  How does that work?

Comment: @moatra: Did you follow the last part of my answer? For `+=` to work, Python needs to retrieve an object on the left-hand side of the equation first (`__getitem__`), then apply `+=`, then when that is done, put the object back where it came from (`__setitem__`).

Comment: My current understanding is that Python translates `d["m"] += 1` to `d["m"] = d["m"] + 1`.  Does it instead translate it to `d["m"] = d["m"] += 1`?  Regardless, where is this behavior specified?

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. See the [augmented assignment documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements).

Comment: If no `__iadd__` method is defined on `d['m']`, then `d['m'] = d['m'] + 1` would be applied, but that's not the case here.

Comment: Ah.  My confusion stemmed from incorrectly thinking `+=` was implemented purely by a magic method --- it's actually a grammar construct.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I swear I've never seen anyone being such a pro @ python ever, period. I would thumbs up x1000 at each answer of yours if I could. Thank you sir! I hope you never retire!

Answer (score 0):

Because, as specified in [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__), `__iadd__` might perform the operation in-place  but the result will be either self or a new object, thus `__setitem__` is called.