# Why is plus-equals valid for list and dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, operator-overloading

Adding a dictionary to a list using the `__iadd__` notation seems to add the keys of the dictionary as elements in the list. Why? For example

```
a = []
b = {'hello': 'world'}
a += b
print(a)  # -> ['hello']
```

[The documentation for plus-equals on collections](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) doesn't imply to me that this should happen:

> For instance, to execute the statement `x += y`, where x is an instance of a class that has an `__iadd__`() method, `x.__iadd__(y)` is called. If x is an instance of a class that does not define a `__iadd__()` method, `x.__add__(y)` and `y.__radd__(x)` are considered, as with the evaluation of `x + y`

But, logically, both `a + b` and `b + a` raise a TypeError. Furthermore, `b += a` raises a TypeError too. I don't see any special implementation [in the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Objects/listobject.c) that would explain things, but I'm not 100% sure where to look.

The closest question on SO I found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569981/python-dictionary-plus-equal-behavior), asking about += on dictionaries, but that's just asking about a data structure with itself. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists) had a promising title about list self-addition, but it claims "`__add__`" is being applied under the hood, which shouldn't be defined between lists and dictionaries.

My best guess is that the `__iadd__` is invoking `extend`, which is [defined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653298/concatenating-two-lists-difference-between-and-extend?rq=1), and then it tries to iterate over the dictionary, which in turn yields its keys. But this seems... weird? And I don't see any intuition of that coming from the docs.

Comment: Your "best guess" is the correct one. Why is that weird?

Comment: when you use `for key in b` then dictionary gives you also `keys`, not `values` . And `list(b)` also gives you `keys`, not `values`. So maybe it works like `a += list(b)`

Comment: @assembly From the docs on collections, I expected += to fail whenever + is undefined (I think of it as shorthand for a = a + b, so it succeeding where that fails is surprising to me). Is it just a quirk of their optimization or something, or is there someone more obvious to look where they explain what the operators do? I guess I just misunderstood what the contract was for the operator..

Comment: @furas, that could be, though my guess is it isn't *explicitly* calling 'a += list(b)' - if it is, and you know of an example of the source code or some PEP backing it up, I'd definitely accept that answer!

Comment: it is not explicity calling `list(b)` but someone decide that `b` will return only keys when you use it with `for`-loop, `list()` and the same in `+=`. Someone decided that keys can be more useful then `values`

Comment: @furas Why doesn't it do the same for `a + b` then? Iterator behaviour is documented but this doesn't seem to be.

Comment: `+` and `+=` may not use the same code - and maybe they don't have time to write it in the same way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> My best guess is that the `__iadd__` is invoking `extend`, which is defined here, and then it tries to iterate over the dictionary, which in turn yields its keys. But this seems... weird? And I don't see any intuition of that coming from the docs.

This is the correct answer for why this happens. I've found the relevant docs that say this-

[In the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#mutable-sequence-types) you can see that in fact `__iadd__` is equivalent to `.extend()`, and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) it says:

> `list.extend(iterable)`: Extend the list by appending all the items from the iterable.

[In the part about dicts](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) it says:

> Performing `list(d)` on a dictionary returns a list of all the keys used in the dictionary

So to summarize, `a_list += a_dict` is equivalet to `a_list.extend(iter(a_dict))`, which is equivalent to `a_list.extend(a_dict.keys())`, which will extend the list with the list of keys in the dictionary.

We can maybe discuss on *why* this is the way things are, but I don't think we will find a clear-cut answer. I think `+=` is a very useful shorthand for `.extend`, and also that a dictionary should be iterable (personally I'd prefer it returning `.items()`, but oh well)

---

**Edit:** You seem to be interested in the actual implementation of CPython, so here are some code pointers:

[dict iterator returning keys](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Objects/dictobject.c#L3401-L3405):

```c
static PyObject *
dict_iter(PyDictObject *dict)
{
    return dictiter_new(dict, &PyDictIterKey_Type);
}
```

[list.extend(iterable) calling iter() on its argument](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Objects/listobject.c#L892):

```c
static PyObject *
list_extend(PyListObject *self, PyObject *iterable)
{
    ...
    it = PyObject_GetIter(iterable);
    ...
}
```

[+= being equivalent to list.extend()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Objects/listobject.c#L969):

```c
static PyObject *
list_inplace_concat(PyListObject *self, PyObject *other)
{
    ...
    result = list_extend(self, other);
    ...
}
```

and then this method seems to be referenced above inside a `PySequenceMethods` struct, which seems to be an abstraction of sequences that defines common actions such as concatenating in-place, and concatenating normally (which is defined as `list_concat` in the same file and you can see is not the same).

Comment: Ah, you found those extra sections on lists. Okay, I buy that, thanks! (I also would prefer for it to return .items... but probably not worth breaking all existing code...)

Comment: @en_Knight I've added some code pointers since you've asked about the implementation itself, hope it helps :)