# Thread-safe iadd in Python dict and MutableMapping

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm writing a dict-like `MutableMapping` class that performs some additional synchronization and I would like to make it thread safe. I can make most standard operations like `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` thread-safe by wrapping them in a lock. However, in-place binary operations seemingly cannot be controlled in this fashion because ultimately those operations are performed on the object within the dict, rather than the dict itself. For example, as discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569981/python-dictionary-plus-equal-behavior) `d['foo'] += 1` ultimately looks something like calls `d__setitem__('foo', d.__getitem__('foo').__iadd__(1))` (both calling an in-place add and setting the value since `__iadd__` attempts to operate in place but also returns self as documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__)).

I assumed that the same limitations would exist for standard dictionaries. To test this behavior, I wrote this simple snippet:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def add_one(d):
    d['threadcount'] += 1  # Option 1
    # d['threadcount'] = d['threadcount'] + 1 # Option 2

x = {}
x['threadcount'] = 0

total = 10000
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
    list(executor.map(add_one, [x] * total))

assert x == total
```

Surprisingly, no matter what I set `max_workers` or `total` to, this test reliably succeeds for both versions of `add_one` shown above. To analyze this further, I looked at the bytecode for the `add_one` method:

```
>>> dis.dis(add_one)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (d)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('threadcount')
              4 DUP_TOP_TWO
              6 BINARY_SUBSCR
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             10 INPLACE_ADD
             12 ROT_THREE
             14 STORE_SUBSCR
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

As I would expect, this simple method in fact consists of many instructions to account for stack pushes necessary for the dict lookup, the in place addition, etc. [Another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1718843) provides further explanation that supports my expectation that this operation would not be thread safe. The Python Language Reference explains that the `+=` operator is a [language construct](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements), so I'm at a loss for how the snippet I posted works as expected regardless. I don't see any way that the dict could acquire the GIL for the entire length of `add_one` method since other Python code needs to perform the integer addition I'm requesting, so how is Python avoiding the expected race condition where `x['threadcount']` would be read as the same value on many threads before any of them can modify it?

**Edit**

Specifying in case it is important, since I suspect that what I'm observing is an implementation detail. I'm running CPython version 3.8.5 on a Mac.

Comment: You are mixing up Python language definitions with CPython interpreter implementation details like the GIL. The observed behaviour can be different on other Python interpreters or even interpreter versions.

Comment: @KlausD. If I'm interpreting your comment correctly, you're pointing out that what I'm observing is an implementation detail and not something defined by the Python standard. If that's what you meant, then I agree. I'm simply looking to confirm that intuition and gain some insight. It seems like that would require using mutex locks not just inside the definition of the dict class, but elsewhere in the language constructs themselves, which is not documented anywhere that I could find.

Comment: To be more clear: I've seen plenty of discussion about how dictionaries (and other built-in types) are thread-safe in CPython, but this is an implementation detail and not something guaranteed by the Python specification. However, the behavior that I'm observing here suggests that not only are dictionaries thread safe, but so are additional parts of the language that I wasn't aware of.